# Custom Dialog pops up unwantedly

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

I'm working on an Android App, recently I found out a small bug. Thing is, even If I don't call the **Custom Alert Dialogbox** function, The Alert Dialog is popping up unwantedly. What must be the reason ?

Providing the code I'm using:-

```
if (booking.isPayable()) {

                        goToActivity(PaymentActivity.class);
                        postModelSticky(booking);
                        finish();
                    }
                    getBookingConfirmation();
```

If the condition is true, then go to a activity, else show the dialogBox. 
**getBookingConfirmation()** is a function which opens the Alert 
DialogBox. But Even if the condition is true, The dialog is popped up before the transition happens.

Comment: hey @Clint Paul 
if (booking.isPayable()) {

                        goToActivity(PaymentActivity.class);
                        postModelSticky(booking);
                        finish();
                    }(TRUE CONDITION FINISH HERE)KEEP ELSE CONDITION HERE
                    getBookingConfirmation();
in this code if your condition is true after that                     getBookingConfirmation() is callled always so u have to keep else condition

Comment: @santoXme Thanks !!! 
\m/ 
Tried your solution , it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an `else` in your code

```
                   if (booking.isPayable()) 
                   {

                        goToActivity(PaymentActivity.class);
                        postModelSticky(booking);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    getBookingConfirmation();
```

Comment: Yes. I missed the 'else' part. Thnks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
if (booking.isPayable()) {
   goToActivity(PaymentActivity.class);
   postModelSticky(booking);
   finish();
}            
else{
   getBookingConfirmation();
 }
```

Use Else Case cause getBookingConfirmation will be called even after finish

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialoge.

So plz First You try it....
using this Solve your error

gradle Librery:

```
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
```

Dialoge Example:

```
if (booking.isPayable()) {

                        goToActivity(PaymentActivity.class);
                        postModelSticky(booking);
                        finish();
                    }
                    getBookingConfirmation();


 new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Oops... No Internet Connection")
                        .setContentText("No internet connection on your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                        .setConfirmText("Enable Internet")
                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(dialogIntent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setConfirmText("Cancel")
                        .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
```